# How can I make Karliah leave the Snow Veil Sanctum and show up at the Ragged Flagon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Karlia never showed up at the Ragged Flagon: I was reading up on this and I saw that she can get caught at Snow Veil Sanctum. I returned and ran through to the sanctum and found that yes, she was there. I had brought the Falmor Translations to the Frozen Hearth and everything, and I am ready to confront Mercer. She, however, won't show at the Ragged Flagon.

I have waited for ten Skyrim days. I am currently in the sanctum looking at her and she won't converse. Every time I wait I find that she is either in another place in the sanctum or standing in her previous spot, practically mocking me. Any suggestions?

I have been reading through questions here and they are all similar but never exact. I play on an Xbox 360, so PC and PS3 won't help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a map reset.

Go to an area far away from both Karliah and the quest destination, then rest for 30 days straight.  This should reset the NPC and actually cause her to show up at the destination.

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is either revert to a previous save. Seems that that's all you can do to fix things (bunch of trial and error).

If you WERE on PC, you could potentially use the console commands:

```
RECYCLEACTOR
```

or

```
{click object actor is getting stuck on and} DISABLE [close console, wait a couple seconds, open console and] ENABLE.
```

I've learned the hard way about saving at every quest step... (I play with autosave disabled to prevent most CTDs and frame drops, so Quicksaving/Normal Saves have become a habit.)

Comment: Believe me pal, I wish I were pc. I prefer pc BECAUSE of command controls.